# android service implement runnable?

Tags: android, service

Recently, I see a class, says class A, which "extends Service implements Runnable".

Is that means I can create a lot of A service? Besides, I really want to know that

if I create 10 A services, each of A services will use 10 MB memory, and the android limitation memory is 50 MB, will I get the out of memory and crash the program?

Comment: What kind of service are you running that will take up 10mb?

Comment: It just a example; however, it is quite easy to take more than 10mb. such as mediaScanner.